# XSLT change string to date

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to grab the attribute @start and @stop and change it in to a date using XSLT.

It's a quite strange date format that I can't change (school assignment).

```
<programme start="20181011154000 +0200" stop="20181011172000 +0200" channel="1.bluemovie.de" clumpidx="0/1">
```

I've come this far

```
<xsl:variable name="start" select="@start"/>
                                        <xsl:variable name="stop" select="@stop"/>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($start, '')"/>
```

I run in to a problem when supplying the second argument to the format-dateTime function.

Any ideas how I could format this?

Answer (score 2):

So you have an input string of the form `20181011154000 +0200`, into which XSLT/XPath 2.0 `xs:date` or `xs:dateTime` do you want to convert it? I suppose into `2018-10-11T15:40:00+02:00`, if the format you have is consistent you can use the `replace` function to construct the right format for an `xs:dateTime` with e.g.

```
xs:dateTime(replace('20181011154000 +0200', '([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\s([+-])([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6$7$8:$9'))
```

So you can write a function

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:date-time-string-to-dateTime" as="xs:dateTime">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="xs:dateTime(replace($input, '([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\s([+-])([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6$7$8:$9'))"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

and use it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:date-time-string-to-dateTime" as="xs:dateTime">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="xs:dateTime(replace($input, '([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\s([+-])([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '$1-$2-$3T$4:$5:$6$7$8:$9'))"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="programme">
      <p>Start {mf:date-time-string-to-dateTime(@start)}, end {mf:date-time-string-to-dateTime(@stop)}</p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaG4